# Cannot read the binlog filename and position via 'SHOW MASTER STATUS'

Tags: mysql, docker-compose, debezium

I am making some POC using `debezium` version 0.9 and I am running a standalon docker-ized mysql database using the embedded Debezium configuration. I am running into this issue:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot read the binlog filename and position via 'SHOW MASTER STATUS'. Make sure your server is correctly configured
```

I suspect it's because the standalone configuration of `mysql` or the embedded configuration, but not sure how to proceed and fix. Any hint?

Comment: Is the binary log enabled on your MySQL instance? It is not enabled by default on a new MySQL 5.x instance, unless you enable it with the log_bin option. MySQL 8.0 enables the binary log by default. Read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/binary-log.html and https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replication-options-binary-log.html#option_mysqld_log-bin

Comment: No, it's not, thanks for the hint and the links.

Comment: @Squake did you got any solution to this problem? I am also on the same boat trying out debezium on local.

Comment: Yes, the comment above provided by Bill solved the problem, it was about the binlog configuration.

Answer (score 1):

As Bill pointed out in the above comment - Debezium connector uses binary log to do its job so it needs to be enabled.

> Debezium MySQL requires enabling the server binlog. In the case of RDS
> MySQL, the log_bin property is managed directly by AWS and is set to
> OFF by default. When Debezium MySQL executes the SHOW MASTER STATUS
> command during a snapshot, the result set is empty and an exception is
> thrown:

https://debezium.io/documentation/faq/

You can check if binlog is enabled with `show master status` and that is the error you are getting from debezium when it's disabled.  The following is an example when binlog is enabled, when it's disabled there would be no rows returned.

```
mysql> show master status;
+------------------+----------+--------------+------------------+--------------------------------------------+
| File             | Position | Binlog_Do_DB | Binlog_Ignore_DB | Executed_Gtid_Set                          |
+------------------+----------+--------------+------------------+--------------------------------------------+
| mysql-bin.000001 |   170796 |              |                  | bf9ae151-baac-11ec-919f-42010a8a0014:1-599 |
+------------------+----------+--------------+------------------+--------------------------------------------+
```

For Google Cloud SQL MySQL 5.x you need to enable point-in-time recovery
https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/backup-recovery/pitr#enablingpitr